# Imagemagick gradient from left and right

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, gradient

I want to use Imagemagick to add a transparent gradient from the left and right to be composed with an image.

I can generate the image with:

```
convert -size 100x100 gradient: -function Polynomial -4,4,0 -distort SRT 90 gradient.png
```

And it looks like:

[image: transparent gradient]

I can also compose that image on top of the image I want with:

```
composite original.jpg -compose Multiply gradient.png final_image.jpg
```

[image: final gradient]

All of this works fine. My question is, how do I change the color of that gradient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around this by doing

```
convert input.jpg -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent -background red -channel A -blur 0x34 -level 75%,100% +channel -flatten final.jpg
```

which works in my case, giving me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add comma-separated colors after `gradient:` option:

```
convert -size 100x100 gradient:white,blue -function Polynomial -4,4,0 -distort SRT 90 gradient.png
```

Note, that `-function` converts channels too, so colors in gradient wont be original.

Comment: Error: `convert: unrecognized color 'white,blue'`

Comment: The proper syntax is gradient:white-blue, with a hyphen not a comma.